# Echo Ajax - PHP, AJAX, Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently I am experiencing a frustrating bug in my code. It seems that I can't echo an ajax call within php.Below is the code for the call. Any suggestions would be much appreciated Thanks.

```
echo'
<script>
$.get("fxn.php", { r: ""+result, id:""+'.$id.' } ).
    success(function(){ 
       alert("FXN"); 
    });
</script>';
```

Note:

1. Result is a javascript variable.
2. $id is a php variable.
3. The success function is never called.

Comment: indent your code and you will find a solution in less than a minute

Comment: If $id is not a number it won't work. I mean... `id: "' . $id . '"`

Comment: Can you explain what you need a + before result? Is this to force a String? Make sure you have no whitespace being passed if you're using something like a switch in your request page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// For those who come after, put a space after echo.
echo 
     // put type into your script tag. Be kind to the older browsers.
     '<script type="text/javascript">'.
     // are you sure jQuery has loaded at this point? Does `$` reference jQuery
     // or is there another framework that's nastying up $? (Liferay? Prototype?)
     '$.get("fxn.php", '.
     // I always prefer explicit casting, but is this defined?
     '{ r: ""+result, id:""+'
     // is $id a string? Then you need to quote it.
     .$id.' } ).'.
     // not necessary, but good practice, use the third parameter of `$.get`
     // instead of defining it externally.
     'success(function() { alert("FXN"); });</script>';
```

Proposed alternate:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
         $.get("fxn.php", { r: String(result), id:"'.$id.'" }, function() { 
            alert("FXN"); 
         });
     </script>';
```

Oh, and are you sure that PHP is returning anything? What happens if you use get manually on `fxn.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`heredoc`](http://php.net/heredoc) to avoid a lot of qouting

```
echo <<< JS
    <script>$.get("fxn.php", { r: ""+result, "id":"$id" } ).success(function() { alert("FXN"); });</script>
JS;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to escape the " characters in your echo. Like below

```
echo '<script>$.get(\"fxn.php\", { r: \"\"+result, id:\"\"+'.$id.' } ).success(function() { alert(\"FXN\"); });</script>';
```

Comment: Double-quotes within single-quotes needs not be escaped.